# protractor without selenium server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

When I issue the protractor command at the command line, with the following configuration:

```
'use strict';

// Protractor configuration
var config = {
  specs: ['test/e2e/*spec.js']
};

if (process.env.TRAVIS) {
  config.capabilities = {
    browserName: 'firefox'
  };
}

exports.config = config;
```

I get this:

```
$ protractor
[12:22:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:22:23] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[12:22:24] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.0.242:55414/wd/hub
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 8.223 seconds

[12:22:33] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[12:22:33] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:22:33] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

the problem is that it takes 5+ seconds to start up the "selenium standalone server".

Two questions - (1) do I need this server to run the tests? And (2), is there a way to run the server in the background without having to restart the server everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also use selenium server jar in the protractor configuration. Checkout the sample bellow. this also comes in handy while using phantojs.

seleniumServerJar: '../utils/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar',

seleniumPort: 4444,

make user seleniumAddress is commented in the config

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the protractor `DirectConnect` option? If so, you can also use the standalone `webdriver-manager`. Protractor also uses it as a dependency.

For local development I installed it as a global with `npm install webdriver-manager -g`, then update it with `webdriver-manager update` and start it with `webdriver-manager start`. It will then run on the background on the default port 4444, run `webdriver-manager` to see all the options.

You then don't need to start the webdriver for each test / suite.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, sorry I forgot to copy my config, just added it to the question. This didn't quite work - is the DirectConnect option a command line flag? Or a config field?

Comment: ok I used "directConnect: true" in my config and it worked - but instead, ideally I could talk to the selenium webdriver server running the background

Comment: Your config is a bit small, if you want to talk to the selenium server in the background you at least need to add `config.seleniumAddress='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';`. Then it will execute all tests on that address.